# MPAndroidChart bar values hide when zooming in

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a horizontal bar chart using minimal code.
The problem is that when I am zooming in the values on the bars disappear.

Before:
[image: before]
After:
[image: after]

The values reappear if -while zoomed in- I drag the chart to the start of the Axis (and disappear again if I drag away).

Is this the expected behavior? Any way to change it?

edit: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/4131

Comment: Can you solve or work around this problem in any way?